# reuse java business logic

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am new to groovy. What my question is, is there any way to reuse my business logic which was written in java? For example Ihave one businesslogin for user authentication which does is login checkin of the user. Can that business logic be used in Groovy? Or should I write different business logic in Groovy style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groovy objects are java objects. you can call your java code from groovy and visa versa.